# I am getting some sort of underlaying line when using dashed lines in pyplot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

This is my code for one of my lab problems in my coding class:

```
t1=np.linspace(-30,-1.6,100)
x1=(3*t1)/(1+t1**3)
y1=(3*t1**2)/(1+t1**3)

t2=np.linspace(-0.6,40,1000)
x2=(3*t2)/(1+t2**3)
y2=(3*t2**2)/(1+t2**3)

plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.plot(x1,y1,color="blue", linestyle="-")
plt.plot(x2,y2,color="green", linestyle="--", dashes=(5,5))

plt.xlabel("x-axis")
plt.ylabel("y-axis")
plt.xlim(-2.5,2)
plt.ylim(-2.5,2)
plt.title("p06")

plt.show()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1P2K.jpg

My program is for some reason imputing this orange line underneath my green dashed line. Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: Figured it out! After messing around with it for a bit I realized that I was redrawing a dashed line over the regular line. After removing the line: ply.plot(x2,y2) it worked. Silly issue.

Comment: If it was a silly issue as you say, you might consider deleting this question as it won't be of use to anyone else